# How to use c# switch parameters in powershell functions?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I have a function

```
getinfo([string]$subcommand, [string]$argument)
```

What I would like to do is allow the argument to be of value '-h' or '-help' such that

```
getinfo hosts -h
```

would give a help text for the subcommand 'hosts'. Unfortunately, when i specify -h I think it doesn't assign the value of "-h" to $argument and instead creates a new argument.

I was thinking of using a switch parameter but I'm not sure if I can use that in a function in conjunction with $argument above.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "C# switch parameters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
getinfo([string]$subcommand, [switch][alias("h")]$Help) {
  switch ($subcommand) {
    'hosts' {
       if ($Help) { 'Usage: getinfo hosts ...'; return }
       ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

All arguments not matching a parameter are automatically stored in the variable `$args`, so you don't really need a parameter `$argument`. It has the advantage (or disadvantage, depending on your point of view), that it accepts even arguments that PowerShell would interpret as parameters. Example:

```
PS C:\> function getinfo($subcommand, [switch]$Help, $argument) {
>>   if ($Help) { 'help' }
>>   $argument
>> }
>>
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' 'b'
b
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' -x
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' 'b' -h
help
b
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' -x -h
help
PS C:\> function getinfo($subcommand, [switch]$Help) {
>>   if ($Help) { 'help' }
>>   $args[0]
>> }
>>
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' 'b'
b
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' -x
-x
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' 'b' -h
help
b
PS C:\> getinfo 'a' -x -h
help
-x
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks so much. I've got info([string]$subcommand, [string]$argument, [string]$filter, [switch][alias("h")]$help). Worked perfectly because as long as -h is set, i'm in business. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Stepping back a bit, you are trying to force a command paradigm on PowerShell that is not what I'd call idiomatic PowerShell.  Why not create several functions each with their own help e.g. Get-HostInfo, Get-FooInfo, etc.  Then you can use PowerShell's built-in documentation support e.g.:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   Short description
.DESCRIPTION
   Long description
.PARAMETER Host
    Name of the host.
.EXAMPLE
   Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
   Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function Get-HostInfo($host) { ... }
```

This supports help in all the ways PowerShell users expect:

```
man Get-HostInfo
man Get-HostInfo -Example
man Get-HostInfo -Parameter Host
Get-HostInfo -?
```

Comment: The built-in documentation is the way to go for defining help information. You want to be able to type `Get-Help` and the command should produce the needed help text. Writing your own code to do this breaks that idea. Let PowerShell do what it is good at.